# How can i create a python app to add images to a template

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, opencsv

I'm trying to create an app to add image to a template image

something like this:

[Image template example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDTSU.png)

I wanna put on the green squares an image, how can i do it automatically, i can do it using pillow or opencsv?

I'm expecting to do something like this

[Template filled with images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B47Dw.png)

Comment: Is it possible to go through the image pixel by pixel taking the positions of each pixel of color #00ff00 in order to have a rectangle? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75607388/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You seem to start off with green rectangles, and say your problem is adding rectangles and then suddenly there are cats??? Please click [edit] and try to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the pixel positions of the areas that should be replaced inside a template and the number of areas to look for? If not, can you guarantee that the template areas are always the same (known) color?